# JavaScript block loop logic

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, logic

My code has an array with numerous objects, these objects which are URL'S, with them I make a loop that runs through this array and makes a request for each url in the array. But I need my loop to go through the array in blocks, Ex: every 10; until you reach the end, all this so that you don't do it instantly and end up overloading the server and also so that it doesn't take too long to go from 1 in 1 because the array is very large, the code base is basically that.

```
const array = ["URL-1","URL-2","URL-3"] etc...

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    axios.get(array[i], (res) => {
        const res = res;
    });
}
```

Comment: You could use a setTimeout?

Comment: the request number is too large to do at once, even using setTimeout. I may end up receiving error 404

Comment: not if you do 10 at a time with a timeout in between?

Comment: this is the question, how do I make the request every 10 in 10 array?

Comment: Split the array up first? `array.splice`

Comment: sounds like a good idea, I'll try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There most be a better way but by using the setTimeOut option you could try

```js
let index = 0;
const maxIterations = 10;

function checkUrls() {

        for (var i = index; i < index + maxIterations; i++) {
            axios.get(array[i], (res) => {
            const res = res;
        }
        index += maxIterations;
        if (index >= array.length - maxIterations) {
            endOfArray = true;
            clearInterval(timer);
        }

}

const timer = setInterval(checkUrls, 10000);
```

Or something along those lines, hope that helps

Comment: I think you did not understand my question very well, in your example he will make the request for the entire 10x array, what I really want is that he only traverses my array once, only in blocks of 10 in 10. Until complete the array.

Comment: And that is what my code is trying to do, every 10sec it will iterate over the array 10 items at a time until it reaches the end

Comment: here, he made the request for 10, and closed it, instead of making another 10 request

Comment: I’ll need to see your current implementation to be able to help further

Comment: [Print Screen](https://prnt.sc/uwtdp2)  [result](https://prnt.sc/uwteed) - I created a new project to test your example

Comment: The for loop should be `for (let i = index; i < index + maxIterations; i++) {`

Comment: I just updated the code that should do the trick, hope that helps

Comment: your answer ended up helping me find the result